# Как правильно вставлять символы

Tags: html, utf-8

Есть такой вопрос:  Как правильно вставлять вот такие вот например символы на страницу html - "ρ Ꭾ Ꮅ 尸 Ҏ  ℍ ℋ ℎ ℌ ℏ ዙ"  В общем такие красивые буквы для красивых ников или прочего. Я в этом не разбираюсь как вы поняли, их бы я хотел вставить на страницу html, кодировка у меня "utf-8" будет ли она подходить и к этим символам? можно ли просто вставить эти буквы в код, в див например, правильно ли это будет? Может это глупый вопрос но я знаю что в html например знак © - копирайт, пишется вот так - "& #169;" Нужно ли так записывать все похожие символы? Я правда в этом вообще не шарю, кто подскажет буду очень благодарен!!)
Хотелось бы также эти буквы вставлять в js, но js не все символы читает, как исправить в чем проблема?

Comment: Не обязательно. это `Unicode` символы. Должны работать и без хештега.

Comment: То есть все эти символы это символы юникода? А такие как копирайт или например такие "༻" это тоже юникод?)

Comment: Да, это все символы `unicode`, что поддерживается, а что нет, вы можете прочитать [на сайте юникода](https://home.unicode.org/)  - как видите любой символ можно ставить без его символического хешкода. Вы также можете на клавиатуре вызывать любой из допустимых символов через комбинацию `ALT + (код символ)`, например если зажать левый альт и набрать на правой клавиатуре цифр где `NUM LOCK` (его надо включить) код `0143` и отпустить альт, у вас появится символ `Џ`. Символ копирайта будет `ALT + 0169`